# Deep links not working on speaker and smart display

Tags: actions-on-google

When testing our AoG, we noticed that deep links currently no longer work properly on speakers (e.g. Google Home) and smart displays (e.g. Google Nest Hub). This behavior has been occurring for several days. Before that, everything was functioning normally. In contrast, deep links in the Google Assistant App still work normally.

Deep links like *"OK Google, ask ActionName for abc"* won't trigger the AoG but return the error message *"The agent returned an empty TTS"*. Deep links like "OK Google, start ActionName and do abc" are working fine.

We tested this behavior in the Actions Console and on real devices like Google Home and Google Nest Hub.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Some of our users (myself included) starting having trouble getting any of our deep links to work (on an already certified action). This has been going on (at least) for weeks.

(Whoa! Your workaround works. "start ActionName and DeepLink" functions... where "ask ActionName to/for DeepLink" doesn't. Nice find.)

https://www.reddit.com/r/GoogleAssistantDev/comments/fxb2ku/deep_links_not_working/

Comment: Seems like it's just the "ask" trigger phrase. I can drop the "and" and all the other trigger phrases work: "talk to", "speak to", etc. I'd be glad it was only limited to "ask", except it's apparently the most natural.

Answer (score 0):

There may have been a bug at the time of posting the question. The bug has since been resolved and I'm unable to reproduce this error today.